# How to connect springboot with MSSQL Server using Hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, mssql-jdbc

I try to connect my Springboot application to my local MSSQL Server with hibernate. For now I've set up a local ms sql server. I couldn't establish a connection to my database using IntelliJ CE and the JPA buddy.

On the net I found a guide that used IntelliJ UE. I installed the 30 day trial and with the ultimate version I could establish a connection with the database (using View->Tool Windows->Database, SSL is not enabled).
[image: IntelliJ Ultimate Database Screenshot]

Even though the URL is kinda messy with "...server://./db". If I replace the '//./' with '//localhost/' it does not work anymore.

Now, I soon won't have access to the ultimate version anymore. So, my question is: **How do I get the same behaviour with the JPA buddy and IntelliJ Community Edition?**

I guess that it is related to the selected driver 'MS SQL Server ->LocalDB<-'.

When I use the following JPA settings, it does not work in the community version (it doesnt matter if I use the 'jtds' driver or not):

[image: IntelliJ Community Database Screenshot]

In both cases I get "Error during login for the user 'dbuser'". (The server is local and I don't have SSL enabled, therefore the ';encrypt=false')

I also tried to use the application.properties with the following content:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;encrypt=false
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=...
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

But this didn't work either.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are missing the port and database in your `spring.datasource.url`. Your param is also wrong. Please try with `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/db?encrypt=false`

Comment: Nope. That actually makes things worse. Then I get: 'Invalid port number:1433/db?encrypt=false'. The seperator definitely is ';' instead of '?'. But even if I use the ';' in that place, I get: invalid port number: '1433/db'. And the port is optional, as 1433 is the standard port for MSSQL and should be used by default by the MSSQL driver

Answer (score 1):

In the JPA Buddy discord channel, it's recommended to use:
encrypt=true and trustServerCertificate=true

Here is the reference: https://discord.com/channels/779011925748219934/995025376222920775/995963092359991317